# Two Robots on a single Roscore

Tags: ros, tf-prefix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello and happy new year :)

I am trying to run Peoplebot and Fetch on the same ROS master.  I have attempted to use a tf_prefix so there wouldn't be a conflict in the TF tree.  However, when I add the tf_prefix "peoplebot" to the global scope in peoplebot's launch file, I get this error:

```
[WARN [1483314575.427997796]: Timed out waiting for transform from peoplebot/base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101242 timeout was 0.1.
```

My questions are:

1. Is tf_prefix the right approach for running multiple robots on a single core or is there a cleaner solution I'm overlooking?
2. Any suggestions how I can solve this problem?  I've been jimmying around with my launch files for over 10 hours now with no avail..

Here is my tf tree before adding the prefix: [image: Original TF Tree]

Here is my tf tree, now disconnected, after adding the global tf_prefix="peoplebot": [image: TF Tree with tf_prefix]

Also, I was able to get the tf tree connected by changing a few other things in the launch file, but still the map doesn't spawn: [image: TF tree after changing laser/sonar's launch]

Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.  Thanks for your help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251089/two-robots-on-a-single-roscore/) by [gsaba](https://answers.ros.org/users/28932/gsaba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
Could you please make images of your pdfs and then attach them directly to this question? I've given you enough karma to make this possible. Reason I ask is because that will make this question self-contained, maintaining its value even if you delete the files from your google drive.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gsaba](https://answers.ros.org/users/28932/gsaba/) on 2017-01-02**:
Thank you for the Karma.  I have edited the post!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:  I was able to connect the graphs by adding a static transform from /map to peoplebot/odom (see image below)

[image: image description]

I am now getting the errors:

```
[WARN] [1483387554.490771420]: The driver/sonar observation buffer has not been updated for 2.07 seconds, and it should be updated every 1.00 second.
```

---

Originally posted by [gsaba](https://answers.ros.org/users/28932/gsaba/) with karma: 36 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-02**:
The transform from map to odom is traditionally provided by localization (AMCL), so  you should probably try to figure out how to configure AMCL to publish that transform.

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-01-03**:
I am having the same problem with multi-robot navigation move_base: errors like "The robot1/scan observation buffer has not been updated for 56.86 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.40 seconds."
Did you resolve this, and if so how? - link to example config files would be greatly appreciated!